# core.js:478 Uncaught Error: Malformed UTF-8 Data When Decrypting Url Query Param in Angular

Tags: angular, encryption, query-string, cryptojs

I have a crypto encrypt and decrypt service below and I use it throughout my application to encrypt and decrypt localstorage items. While it works perfectly fine for the localstorage items, when I try to decrypt an encrypted object sent through queryparams, I get the following error:

```
core.js:478 Uncaught Error: Malformed UTF-8 data
```

My encrypt/decrypt service is:

```js
export class AESEncryptDecryptService {
    
      secretKey = 'My secret string';
      constructor() { }
    
      encrypt(value? : string) : string{
        if(!isNil(value)) {
          return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, this.secretKey.trim()).toString();
        }
      }
    
      decrypt(textToDecrypt?){
        if(!isNil(textToDecrypt)) {
        return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(textToDecrypt, this.secretKey.trim()).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        }
      }
}
```

How I encrypt the object before I sent it:

```
const user= new User();
this.qrUrl =  `${environment.someurl}` +'currentUser=' +this._AESEncryptDecryptService.encrypt(JSON.stringify(user).toString()).toString();
```

How I  decrypt the object:
const url_string = window.location.href;
const url = new URL(url_string);

```
if(url.searchParams.get('user')) {
  this.qrDevice = JSON.parse(this._AESEncryptDecryptService.decrypt(url.searchParams.get('user')));
}
```

I tried it without the string and by debugging. The same code works fine for other uses but gives this error on url query decrypt.

One thing I noticed is that the query string is replacing the + in the string with a space. How can I fix this and preserve the + sign? the expected and actual of the encrypted objects are posted below.

Expected after object parse from URL:

> U2FsdGVkX1+8y4FZ0cDq5ikapUndRA+tE5BAVqYPH9NnhBWeea1asYo5zCU80s/6FWKnFU8FghXv7JxPWwnPpJtCR+eXIGpiGBWq4gpq00PoeIuU2jPsDeifSu8aDrFr+D8abcdkIil5WmsHiND5TwVfWHhaBDSSlYMSXbiUXx9DQgRipEAtXXgMEO/r7G5wpuJ9ekEzUfkgXIO3eM/tP6dMu2iWZwbXTDvBZl93J8XZ259YRtIkRXgolSGS2t9yvQOn9I7fobRI1NSCIAftQtGdj/k9pu4B9reicnw9wiNR4dmp8+cpI/3TQSevhwp

Actual after object parse from url:

> U2FsdGVkX1 8y4FZ0cDq5ikapUndRA
> tE5BAVqYPH9NnhBWeea1asYo5zCU80s/6FWKnFU8FghXv7JxPWwnPpJtCR
> eXIGpiGBWq4gpq00PoeIuU2jPsDeifSu8aDrFr
> D8abcdkIil5WmsHiND5TwVfWHhaBDSSlYMSXbiUXx9DQgRipEAtXXgMEO/r7G5wpuJ9ekEzUfkgXIO3eM/tP6dMu2iWZwbXTDvBZl93J8XZ259YRtIkRXgolSGS2t9yvQOn9I7fobRI1NSCIAftQtGdj/k9pu4B9reicnw9wiNR4dmp8
> cpI/3TQSevhwp

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved by changing the qrurl to the following:

```
 this.qrUrl =  `${environment.qrOrderURL}user=`+encodeURIComponent(this._AESEncryptDecryptService.encrypt(JSON.stringify(user)));
```